# Ansible 'with_items' doesn't pass over to Ansible role

Tags: ansible

I can't figure this out. I have host_vars that I want to pass into my Ansible role. I can iterate through the items in my playbook, but it doesn't work if I give the item into my Ansible role. My host inventory looks like this:

```
hosts:
    host_one:
        domain: one
        ip: 172.18.1.1
        connection:
                - connection_name: two
                  connection_ip: 172.18.1.2

                - connection_index: three
                  local_hub_ip: 172.18.1.3

    host_two:
        domain: two
        ip: 172.18.1.2
```

For instance,this works correctly:

```
  tasks:
    - debug:
          msg: "{{item.connection_name}}"
      with_items:
          - "{{ connection }}"
```

will correctly print out the connections.connection_name for each connection I have, "two" and "three". However, if I try to pass it into a role:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Adding several connections
      include_role:
          name: connection-create
      with_items:
          - "{{ connection }}"
```

in which my role "connection-create" uses a variable called "connection_name" I get a:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "'connection_name' is undefined"}

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop *with_items: "{{ connection }}"* creates the loop variable *item*. The included role can use

```
item.connection_name
item.connection_ip
```

The loop variable can be renamed, if needed. See [Loop control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control)

Comment: I see, the issue was in my role I had another "with_items" task so I had to restructure it so I could use the 'item.connection_name'